Livewire Component is not listening to events from child component
Hello I need help with events because right now, I can trigger events in same component but can't detect in parent component:
My current workflow is:

Order Now button is clicked
Calls OrderForm Component

<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Component;

class OrderForm extends Component
{
    public $currentStep = 1;

    #[On('goToPricing')]
    public function goToPricing($assignmentDetails)
    {
        info("It works here");
        $this->currentStep = 2;
        $this->dispatch('order-pricing', 'goToPricing', $assignmentDetails);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.order-form');
    }
}


Now, order-form.blade.php:
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="px-4 py-20 bg-orange-100">
    @if($currentStep == 1)
    @livewire('assignment-details')
    @elseif($currentStep == 2)
    @livewire('order-pricing')
    @endif
</div>

@endsection

and yes it shows AssignmentDetails.php on frontend:
AssignmentDetails.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class AssignmentDetails extends Component
{
    // some variables

    public function submit()
    {
        info("happenXXX");

        $this->dispatch('goToPricing', 'someData');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        
        return view('livewire.assignment-details');
    }
}


Here is assignment-details view:
<div class="p-6 bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg">
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit" class="space-y-4">
        <div>
            <label for="assignment_type" class="block text-gray-700">Assignment Type</label>
            <input type="text" id="assignment_type" wire:model="assignment_type" class="mt-1 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md w-full">
            @error('assignment_type') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="discipline" class="block text-gray-700">Discipline</label>
            <input type="text" id="discipline" wire:model="discipline" class="mt-1 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md w-full">
            @error('discipline') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="academic_level" class="block text-gray-700">Academic Level</label>
            <input type="text" id="academic_level" wire:model="academic_level" class="mt-1 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md w-full">
            @error('academic_level') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="deadline" class="block text-gray-700">Deadline</label>
            <input type="date" id="deadline" wire:model="deadline" class="mt-1 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md w-full">
            @error('deadline') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="pages" class="block text-gray-700">Pages</label>
            <input type="number" id="pages" wire:model="pages" class="mt-1 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md w-full">
            @error('pages') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="slides" class="block text-gray-700">PowerPoint Slides (optional)</label>
            <input type="number" id="slides" wire:model="slides" class="mt-1 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md w-full">
            @error('slides') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="paper_format" class="block text-gray-700">Paper Format</label>
            <input type="text" id="paper_format" wire:model="paper_format" class="mt-1 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md w-full">
            @error('paper_format') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <!-- Account Section -->
        <div>
            <label for="email" class="block text-gray-700">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" wire:model="email" class="mt-1 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md w-full">
            @error('email') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password" class="block text-gray-700">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" wire:model="password" class="mt-1 p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md w-full">
            @error('password') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>



        <div class="flex justify-between">
            <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-600">Next: Order Pricing</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

Now the problem is, that the event triggered when I submitted the form on AssignmentDetails view is not being listened by the OrderForm component... But I tried to fire and listen to the event in the same component, AssignmentDetails using self with dispatch, and it works fine.
But I want to listen to the OrderForm component to make my flow work.
Thanks.
